# multicasting group

Tags: networking

is it possible to know uninque ip addresses of node having same group id(multicasting group)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for in multicast terms are the members of a given group.

The 'official' way is to multicast a membership query to the group, to which each local member (on the same network) will respond. Takes a bit of network programming to create the query and parse the responses.

The 'unofficial' way is to simply ICMP ping the group address. Most members will respond.
Something like
ping -I eth0 -t 1 -c 10 239.1.0.5

Comment: Actually i want to send a packet only one of the node(any one) which is the member of a particular group and i have only group id of these group.